# How to use Windows Biometric Framework (WBF) in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, biometrics

I'm working on WPF application which should identify user using Fingerprint Reader.

It seems Windows Biometric Framework (WBF) is good enough for this task but I can't found examples where I can see how it can be used in my WPF application. Couple found examples use WBF to verify user currently logged in.
But my application should work with custom users and windows authentication is not acceptable.
I found also small MSDN article where described three sensor pools, one of them should be used in my situation. It is not clear how I can move Fingerprint Reader device between pools, where to get C# wrapper for Biometric API and how all of these things can be used together.

I'm using UPEK Eikon as fingerprint reader device and Windows7 based tablet PC where my application should run.

Could you please help and give me examples and links on useful resources?
Thanks
Dmitry

Comment: Here is a wrapper for .NET https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/WinBiometricDotNet should run this project as Administrator

Answer (score -1):

There are complete C++ examples in the WBF documentation NOW.

I'd like to know where you:

> "found examples use WBF to verify user currently logged in"

as those should then show you how to call the WBF API from WPF.